# Left Joining same table but with different values?

Tags: mysql

**Table_A** has **entity_id**

**Table_B** has a related **entity_id** with **attribute_id** = 1

**Table_B** has a related **entity_id** with **attribute_id** = 2

```
  SELECT Table_B.value
    FROM  Table_A
    LEFT JOIN Table_B
    ON Table_A.entity_id = Table_B.entity_id
    WHERE Table_A.date =  '2012-7-30 00:00:00'
    AND Table_B.attribute_id = 1
```

I would like to get attribute_id = 1 and attribute_id = 2 into one query.

Comment: It's a relation one to many ? I mean, the two are attributes are in the same column ? (which means, differents rows) ? In that case, Table_b.Value which value will show ? from which row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can join Table_B a second time and use AS to give it a new name (an alias).

```
SELECT Table_B.value, Table_B2.value
FROM  Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.entity_id = Table_B.entity_id
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS Table_B2
ON Table_A.entity_id = Table_B2.entity_id
WHERE Table_A.date =  '2012-7-30 00:00:00'
AND Table_B.attribute_id = 1
AND Table_B2.attribute_id = 2
```

You can also move the attribute criteria to make it a little clearer what you're up to:

```
SELECT Table_B.value, Table_B2.value
FROM  Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.entity_id = Table_B.entity_id AND Table_B.attribute_id = 1
LEFT JOIN Table_B AS Table_B2
ON Table_A.entity_id = Table_B2.entity_id AND Table_B2.attribute_id = 2
WHERE Table_A.date =  '2012-7-30 00:00:00'
```

Comment: Shouldn't one of those comparisons be `Table_B2.entity_id`?

Comment: @Andrew you my friend, are a freaking genius :)

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it simply with two easy ways

```
select 
    t1.entity_id,
    t2.attribute
from t1
left join t2 on t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id;
```

OR

```
select 
    t1.entity_id,
    group_concat(t2.attribute) as Attr
from t1
left join t2 on t2.entity_id = t1.entity_id
group by t1.entity_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use OR for the condition if you want to get both attribute_id = 1 and 2?

```
SELECT Table_B.value
FROM  Table_A
LEFT JOIN Table_B
ON Table_A.entity_id = Table_B.entity_id
WHERE Table_A.date =  '2012-7-30 00:00:00'
AND (Table_B.attribute_id = 1 OR Table_B.attribute_id = 2)
```